# Offloading video encoding to another processor for Live Streaming

Tags: video-streaming, video-capture, video-encoding, adobe-media-encoder

So I've been trying to stream myself playing Starcraft 2 for community feedback and whatnot.  I'm able to stream, but I suppose my hardware isn't quite fast enough to handle high quality encoding and rendering the game with decent image quality at the same time.  I have a Core i5 750 and a HD5850 for graphics, so I thought I'd have enough horsepower to achieve this, but I guess not.

Now, I do have a laptop that is pretty powerful, so I was trying to devise a way to offload the expensive real-time encoding process to its CPU.  I'm no expert in this by any stretch of the imagination, but I assumed that I could take a dshow capture of my game screen and output it raw over a rtp (or something else) stream across my local network where my laptop would receive it, encode, and broadcast to the streaming site (in this case justin.tv).

So far I haven't been able to make this work, but I'm not sure if it's just because I don't have it refined yet or because the idea is bad.  Or if there is a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: What are you using to capture the video right now?

Comment: I've used vhscrcap, xsplit, and more recently VLC.